# replacing a smallcaps to allcaps text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble to convert all lower case to upper case in a text box:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input_1" class="allcaps"/>
    <input type="text" id="input_2" class="allcaps"/>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {

    //trigger ng event

    $('.alcaps').live("keyup", function () {
       var fin =   $('.alcaps').val();
       $('.alcaps').val(fin.toUpperCase());
    });                     
});
```

The first input box transforms its contents to capitals, but the text I put in the first box is also copied to the second input...

Answer (score 5):

When using the class as selector you're selecting all input boxes with that class and setting the value to the same as the first one. Use the `this` keyword to target only the current textbox :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', '.alcaps', function() {
        var fin = this.value;
        this.value = fin.toUpperCase();
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANQbW/1/)

Comment: i got it $('.smallcaps').live("keyup", function () {

                var fin =   $(this).val();
               
                $(this).val(fin.toLowerCase());

Comment: Are the inputs inserted dynamically with javascript? If not there's no reason to use `live()`, and in most cases you should'nt use `live()` at all as it's deprecated and has been replaced with `on()`.

Comment: yes they are inserted dynamically.. tnx for the on() thing im still new in jquery..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` which refers to your current input, also note than `live` is deprecated, you can use `on` instead:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".alcaps", function () {
     this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User `this` inside the handler:

```
$('.alcaps').live("keyup", function () {
     var fin =   $(this).val();
     $(this).val(fin.toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
         
         //trigger ng event
         
                $('.alcaps').live("keyup", function () {

                  var fin =   $(this).val();
               
                $(this).val(fin.toUpperCase());
                });
             
                $('.smallcaps').live("keyup", function () {

                var fin =   $(this).val();
               
                $(this).val(fin.toLowerCase());

                    });
                     
                });